# Why both boost convertor and boost controller are required here?

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply

I was looking at the T1 reference design http://www.ti.com/tool/pmp8921#descriptionArea which is a 12V@4A Sync Boost Converter Operating from Single or Dual Li-Ion Batteries .
I am unable to understand why have we used a boost convertor(TPS63061) as well a boost controller(TPS43061 ). Won't one of them say the boost converter(TPS63061) do the job here ?

Thanks,
Ankit

Answer (score 2):

The [schematic](http://www.ti.com/lit/df/slvrb63/slvrb63.pdf) for that reference design makes it pretty clear.
The TPS63061 boost converter provides a boosted, low-current supply for the TPS43061 boost controller's internals to run from.

That circuit has been designed to be able to run from a single Li-Ion cell, but the TPS43061 controller requires at least a 4.5V supply - which a single-cell can't provide.

But even though the controller is running its internals fro the boosted supply, it is controlling its FET which is running directly from the battery.

So the TPS63061 is only supplying the TPS43061, while the TPS43061 controls the FET which supplies the output.

If you don't require the single-cell functionality, you can remove the TPS63061 and connect the TPS43061's Vin pin directly to the input supply.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but this isn't just a board with a power supply on it. The board is meant to be used to evaluate the boost converter under different conditions.

[image]

It looks like this setup was intended to give the user the option to easily vary the supply voltage going to the DUT, as well as bypass it entirely to inject an external source.

Answer (score 0):

The TPS43061 needs a minimum Vin supply voltage of 4.5V.  That means it can't operate from a single cell Li-Ion battery.  The TPS63061 can operate down to 2.5V, but it has much lower current capability than the main boost converter.  So the 63061 ensures that the 43061 has adequate supply voltage over the input voltage range, and the 43061 supplies the higher current.